# Wordpress Install and Database on separate hosting?

Tags: database, mysql

I have a situation where it would be ideal to have the database on separate hosting. Just because the host of the current site does not offer mysql. I cannot move the site (for a company)

Can I install wordpress on current hosting in a sub domain and have the database on another host? I have never used anything except “localhost” in the wp-config file? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes - absolutely.   Simply enter the appropriate hostname and credentials in wp-config.php.   Instead of the default `localhost` use the hostname provided by your database provider.

Example:

```
define( 'DB_HOST', 'mysql.example.com:3307' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Set_Database_Host

Comment: And also make sure that your external database host allows remote connections and is secure.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can. You can specify the hostname or ip address of the DB server and communicate with it.

In practice this is unlikely to work well because:

1. Performance might suck. The speed of information transfer on the same server or in a LAN is much higher than what you will get when you need to communicate over the internet
2. You will have to leave the DB open to attacks. DBs are rarely exposed directly to the internet and I am not sure how good is MySQL security track record, but even in the best case you will have to worry about attacks on two servers instead of one.

Short version: don't do it. If the hosting sucks you either need to go away or select a different CMS that fits better what you can get from the hosting

Answer (score 0):

This question to my opinion is very important. I still do research on how to store the data on a specific local RAID. I dont think there is going to be a lack of performance doing so. If wordpress is on a RAID-10 and the database on a RAID-5 HDD within local hardware I am curious to know what can be wrong?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/251495)